# Selenium not finding LiveValidation text

Tags: jquery, selenium

I am using the Selenium IDE to test some of my web development. I am using the JQuery LiveValidation in my code. I have an input box with some javascript behind it that will do a regular expresson and either ouput "OK" or "Error" next to the input text box based on what the user has entered.

For some reason when testing with selenium the LiveValidation will not get triggered no matter what I do and therefore I can not test it. When I do it manually it works great. Has anyone run into this problem before? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are using the `Type`. The type command dumps text into an input box. Try using the `KeyPress` instead as that tries to synthesize a user doing keypresses.